# Undefined reference error/cannot find -ljpeg

Tags: c++, sfml

So I had the code-blocks 64-bit version installed. And for sfml I installed the GCC 7.3.0 MinGw(SEH) 64-bit. Followed a lot of tutorials and linked everything in the right order. Then I got this error:

ld.exe||cannot find -ljpeg|

||error: ld returned 1 exit status|

I have no idea if this was the right approach to it but I installed libjpeg and moved a libjpeg.dll.a file to the lib folder in sfml. After that, it was the following error:

||=== Build: Debug in lol (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':| C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|5|undefined reference to` sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'|
C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|5|undefined reference to `sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'| C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|5|undefined reference to` sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)'|
C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|6|undefined reference to `sf::CircleShape::CircleShape(float, unsigned int)'| C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|7|undefined reference to` sf::Color::Green'|
C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|7|undefined reference to `sf::Shape::setFillColor(sf::Color const&)'| C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|9|undefined reference to` sf::Window::isOpen() const'|
C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|12|undefined reference to `sf::Window::pollEvent(sf::Event&)'| C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|15|undefined reference to` sf::Window::close()'|
C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|18|undefined reference to `sf::Color::Color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'| C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|18|undefined reference to` sf::RenderTarget::clear(sf::Color const&)'|
C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|19|undefined reference to `sf::RenderStates::Default'| C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|19|undefined reference to` sf::RenderTarget::draw(sf::Drawable const&, sf::RenderStates const&)'|
C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|20|undefined reference to `sf::Window::display()'| C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|5|undefined reference to` sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'|
C:\Users\roseb\OneDrive\Documents\projects\lol\main.cpp|5|undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'| obj\Debug\main.o||In function` ZN2sf11CircleShapeD1Ev':|
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\sfml\include\SFML\Graphics\CircleShape.hpp|41|undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'| C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\sfml\include\SFML\Graphics\CircleShape.hpp|41|undefined reference to` vtable for sf::CircleShape'|
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\sfml\include\SFML\Graphics\CircleShape.hpp|41|undefined reference to `sf::Shape::~Shape()'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 20 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

I removed the libjpeg.dll.a file from the folder and it's the cannot find -ljpeg error again. How do I solve this.
P.s I apologize if my doubts are unbelievably stupid. I've been wanting to learn game development and have been stuck at this for a while.

Btw here's the code:

```
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

 int main()
 {
     sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML 
     works!");
     sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
     shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

     while (window.isOpen())
     {
         sf::Event event;
         while (window.pollEvent(event))
         {
             if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                 window.close();
          }

          window.clear();
          window.draw(shape);
          window.display();
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Are you including the right library?

Comment: apparently you need more than just libjpeg. Like maybe libsfml.

Comment: As per [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/compile-with-cmake.php) website _"On Windows and macOS, all the required dependencies are provided alongside SFML so you won't have to download/install anything else. Building will work out of the box."_

Comment: The following error suggests that you have not linked the SFML library. _"undefined reference to sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'._ Have you configured the code block to link SFML libraries?

Comment: Try link `sfml-window-s.lib
sfml-system-s.lib
opengl32.lib
freetype.lib`

Comment: *moved a libjpeg.dll.a file to the lib folder in sfml* That was a mistake, What's the point of installing if you then have to copy the installed files. Your compilations should be set up to find libraries in the installed locations. But probably nothing to do with your current problems, just storing up possible future problems.

Comment: @kmodexc  I've linked it in the order    sfml-graphics-s-d
sfml-window-s-d
sfml-audio-s-d
sfml-network-s-d
sfml-system-s-d
freetype
opengl32
jpeg
gdi32
winmm
ws2_32
openal32
flac
vorbisenc
vorbisfile
vorbis
ogg

Comment: @john I checked inside the lib folder where there were all the other files and jpeg.a was missing. That's why I tried that but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Aamir I think I have linked it in the proper order. I've linked it in the compiler settings as well as the build options.

Comment: @Nozode can you post the exact command with which the linker is called? If you have a toolchain running, it might have a verbose mode. Its impossible that the compiller misses a library which you did not told him to link like libjpeg.

Comment: sfml-graphics-s-d sfml-window-s-d sfml-audio-s-d sfml-network-s-d sfml-system-s-d freetype opengl32 jpeg gdi32 winmm ws2_32 openal32 flac vorbisenc vorbisfile vorbis ogg